# Can you enable a global for a single line in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

The two options I know of to ignore an exceptional use of a global is

```js
/* global document */

document.querySelector('ihd05NeRDE');
```

or

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
document.querySelector('ihd05NeRDE');
```

The former focuses on a single keyword `document`, but is unfortunately file-wide. The latter applies to a single line, but unfortunately disables the rule for all other keywords.

Is it possible to target a global ignore for a single line like this psuedocode?

```js
// global-enable-next-line document
document.querySelector('ihd05NeRDE');
```

Comment: If you have a global variable, why wouldn't you want to enable it file-wide?

Comment: I still want to discourage its use, but this is an exceptional case.